# Videogular not working in Firefox 39.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, videogular

I am trying out Videogular following is my HTML template,

```
<videogular>
                    <vg-media vg-src="vsource.sources">
                    </vg-media>

                    <vg-controls>
                      <vg-play-pause-button></vg-play-pause-button>
                      <vg-time-display>{{ currentTime | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
                      <vg-scrub-bar>
                        <vg-scrub-bar-current-time></vg-scrub-bar-current-time>
                      </vg-scrub-bar>
                      <vg-time-display>{{ timeLeft | date:'mm:ss' }}</vg-time-display>
                      <vg-volume>
                        <vg-mute-button></vg-mute-button>
                        <vg-volume-bar></vg-volume-bar>
                      </vg-volume>
                      <vg-fullscreen-button></vg-fullscreen-button>
                    </vg-controls>

                    <vg-overlay-play></vg-overlay-play>
                    <!-- <vg-poster vg-url='controller.config.plugins.poster'></vg-poster> -->

                  </videogular>
```

It is working properly on Chrome. But in Firefox the Video tag is empty.
It is like `<Video></video>` . But in chrome it is proper with source and type.

Comment: I am getting same issue I came to know that Firefox doesn't support mp4 video format here are more details about it https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=viewing-html5-audio-and-video you should try with plugins like jwplayer etc.